# JavaScript match array and splice but fails

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `list` an array of `guid` values which will match the `guid` of `people`.

If `list` has the value of `'c7835c96-8dcc-b6e2-e452-494fe4d5fbc5'` then the below code should find

```
{
    'guid': 'c7835c96-8dcc-b6e2-e452-494fe4d5fbc5',
    'name': 'Stan Marsh'
}
```

and remove it from the array `people` and also from `list`.

The problem I have is that the script seems to stop after the first item and I can't figure how to get it to then loop through again to remove the next item in `list`.

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/bangsi/pzh63gL6/)

```
var list = ['c7835c96-8dcc-b6e2-e452-494fe4d5fbc5', '2d5ced81-5ee6-007b-de4c-bd3e5ab2c1fb'];
var people = [{
    'guid': 'c7835c96-8dcc-b6e2-e452-494fe4d5fbc5',
    'name': 'Stan Marsh'
    },{
    'guid': '6d1312f9-1cf3-dc23-c4f5-b216888d8641',
    'name': 'Eric Cartman'
    },{
    'guid': '2d5ced81-5ee6-007b-de4c-bd3e5ab2c1fb',
    'name': 'Kyle Brovlovski'
    },{
    'guid': '536a6f47-2049-5b1a-792c-11cc4f12b7c7',
    'name': 'Kenny McCormick'
    }
];

function arrayObjectIndexOf(myArray, searchTerm, property) {
  for (var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (myArray[i][property] === searchTerm) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

list.filter(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
    var index = arrayObjectIndexOf(people, val, 'guid');
    people.splice(index, 1);

    var i = list.indexOf(val);
    list.splice(i, 1);

    console.info(people);
    console.info(list);
});

console.log('=-----=');
```

Comment: Anyways it's never good to cut the tree branch under yourself. You're modifying `list` during iterating it with `filter`. You probably should gather the indices to remove from the `list` in a separate array, and remove them after the `filter` finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest changing the code to the following:

```
list = list.filter(function(val) {
    var index = arrayObjectIndexOf(people, val, 'guid');
    if (index !== -1) {
        people.splice(index, 1);
    }
    return index == -1;
});
```

The problem with the original code was that, as Zoltán commented, it was modifying the list while iterating over it, so on the second
iteration, the filter function decided it had already gone through all the items, since it was up to item [1] and the length of the array was now only 1.

There is no need to modify the list manually however because filter returns a new array containing the those items for which the callback
returns true, so we just have to return true when the item is *not* found and assign filter's result back to list.

Another problem was that it was performing a splice even when the item was not found (a call to splice with the start parameter as -1 removes the last item from the array).

Comment: This is aces Jon!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove the items matching the guid you can use *filter* like this:

```
var guid =  'c7835c96-8dcc-b6e2-e452-494fe4d5fbc5';
var people = people.filter(function(item) {
    return item.guid !== guid;
})
console.log(people);
```

and similarly for the other array:

```
list = list.filter(function(item) {
    return item !== guid;
})
console.log(list);
```

[Example](https://jsbin.com/xorunu/edit?js,console)

To remove items contained in *list*:

```
var people = people.filter(function(item) {
    return !list.some(function(i) { return item.guid == i; });
})
```

[Example](https://jsbin.com/xorunu/edit?js,console)

Comment: This only handles removing one item from the list though

Comment: Ah, sorry, was looking at your filter function. So you want to remove people from the array whose guids are contained in the list? I'll update my answer.